# How do i share a article content along with another page/profile (author) link which can be previewable on mouse hover?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

[previw-img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y4GDE.png)

I having an issue with facebook post share and i'm using  facebook php SDK along with the open graph. What I actually want to do is that share a post content , image and along with author name and its profile link as same as the above attach an image but I can't figure it out how to do it. If someone here already has this kind of implementation please help me out, I'll be very thankful.

Comment: This is a simple mention tag inside the message content; but you can not tag user profiles in the message of posts published via API, only pages.

Comment: Do you have any example.. and did check my attached sample image that is what I exactly want .. please let me know.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v3.2/page/feed#publish describes how you can tag other pages in your page posts made via API.